# wp_upload_dir how to get just the directory name .

Tags: uploads

I imagine that this would be a breeze for some - but I'm having difficulty getting just the upload's directory name - not the full path - I've gotten this far:

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_path = $uploads['baseurl']; // now how to get just the directory name?
```

anyone have any ideas?
thanks for sharing your experience. . .

Comment: `basename($uploads['baseurl'])` ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is what you get back from the function:

```
Array
(
    [path] => C:\development\xampp\htdocs\example.com/content/uploads/2012/04
    [url] => http://example.com/content/uploads/2012/04
    [subdir] => /2012/04
    [basedir] => C:\~\example.com/content/uploads
    [baseurl] => http://example.com/content/uploads
    [error] => 
)
```

So you can get the (as @OneTrickPony pointed out), folder/directory name with

```
echo wp_basename( $uploads['baseurl'] );
```

If you're running multisite and you defined the constant `UPLOADS`, then you access it from `UPLOADS` or `BLOGUPLOADDIR`.

**EDIT**

For multisites, you would get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [path] => /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/12,
    [url] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/12,
    [subdir] => /2016/12,
    [basedir] => /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/sites/2,
    [baseurl] => http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2,
    [error] => ,
)
```

Where the "2" after `sites` is the blog's ID

Comment: - thanks to both of you there. basename and after some research wp_basename too I'd reckon.

Comment: wp_basename is the  "i18n friendly version of basename()"

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_basename